# How can I handle multiple client connections and respond to them concurrently in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.6

I am setting up a proxy that will accept input from a client(s) relay that request to a server, and then forward the response back to the client. The problem I am running into is how to communicate with multiple clients concurrently. I am trying to use python multi-threading, but I have not been successful. My code looks like this:

```
while True:
    (client_socket, addr) = self.sock.accept()
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_start(client_socket))
    t.start()
```

Where thread_start() starts running the operations of talking to the client.

This code will accept multiple clients, but each client must wait for the previously connected client to close before being able to send data.

I know that sock.accept() will accept multiple clients, but it seems it just puts them into a queue until the previous is finished. Is there a way to be able to talk to multiple clients at a time?

Edit: I appeared to have gotten the correct behavior by simply changing

```
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_start(client_socket))
    t.start()
```

with

```
import _thread
_thread.start_new_thread(self.thread_start, (clientsocket,))
```

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use case for https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a coding assignment and we are not allowed to use anything but the basic socket library and a few other low level libraries.

Comment: Can you use `select`, which is also in the standard library?